# Mongo Collection with TTL index not reclaiming disk space

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with TTL index. I see the documents  are getting evicted as expected but i dont see that the disk space is getting reclaimed. Did anyone see this kind of issue?

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: See the docs: [How do I reclaim disk space in WiredTiger?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space-in-wiredtiger).

Comment: I have one more question. If you say drop a collection of 1GB space would that space be reclaimed or should we still do a compaction?

Answer (score 1):

We have discussed this with mongo team and based on all information there are couple of things and its not that easy

1. If you have already have more space then TTL will delete documents and ideally space should be reclaimed but it will not.
2. If new documents will come then it will be reused
3. If size is going to remain constant then you need to run compact command. In case of sharded cluster it will be on each shard.
4. Other options are create new collection and move your data to newer collection. and once done drop the previous collection
5. Take backup of this collection and drop collection and then restore it.
6. After all this things, there is possibility that mongo holds all in memory and you need to restart cluster, once restarted it will release the storage.